# Cauchy sequence question

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $f$ be a continuous function  in $ (0,1)$.

Determine of the following is right or wrong:

If $ (x_n) $ is a Cauchy sequence such that $0< (x_n) <1$ then $f(x_n) $ is a Cauchy sequence.

Actually... I don't know where to start. How to approach this question?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $f(x) = 1/x$, and the sequence $x_n = 1/n$, which is evidently a Cauchy sequence.

Letting $y_n = f(x_n)$, you get that $y_n = 1/(1/n) = n$, which is not a Cauchy sequence.

As for your real question, which is "where do I start?", my answer is this:

A Cauchy sequence is one where the terms eventually stay very near each other, but a continuous function can stretch things apart...so if we can just find a continuous function that does this enough to make our sequence non-Cauchy, we're done. Now comes the hard part: finding a function that pulls apart nearby items, no matter how nearby they are. Such a function, if differentiable, would have to have infinite derivative at the limit point. That doesn't make sense for continuous functions, so it must be that the limit point for the sequence is not actually at a point where $f$ is well-defined. And then if the derivative of $f$ approaches infinity as we head to that limit, everything will work out.

Well, a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ has a limit, so the only hope we've got is to pick a sequence in $(0, 1)$ whose limit falls outside...and an easy choice is something like $1/n$.

And now we have to find a function whose derivative goes to infinity as $x \to 0$. Everyone's favorite is $f(x) = 1/x$. Combine, and it happens to work out really nicely.

Comment: Thank you! I do have to practice these questions.

Comment: @John Hughes: a small comment on the sentence *"Such a function, if differentiable, would have to have infinite derivative at the limit point. That doesn't make sense for continuous functions"*... Is it actually true? Consider the function $f\colon x\in(0,1) \mapsto x\ln x$, which can be extended by continuity to $[0,1]$ (and is therefore even uniformly continuous there). It is differentiable on $(0,1)$, but with $f^\prime \to_0 -\infty$.

Comment: Great point. It's the second sentence that's wrong. I guess I should have said "here's what I was informally  thinking as I cooked up that example." What's true is that a function that "pulls apart the points enough" can't be continuous at the limit point, but having infinite derivative there isn't enough to ensure a discontinuity. (As $y = \sqrt{x}$ shows even more simply than your example.)

Answer (score 1):

**Idea:** Since [every uniformly continuous function is Cauchy-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function#Properties) (and what you want is an example of continuous function on $(0,1)$ contradicting Cauchy continuity), a natural start is to consider a continuous function $f$ that is *not* uniformly continuous. In particular, it'll have to have a "problem" at one of the endpoints, $0$ or $1$; which in turn implies that $(x_n)_n$ should converge (being Cauchy, it'll have to converge) to either $0$ or $1$ for the "bad behavior" of $f$ to manifest itself.

**Hint:** now, take your favorite continuous-but-not-uniformly-continuous function $f$ on $(0,1)$, say with a uniform continuity issue at $0$ (there is a good chance it'll work, i.e. will not be Cauchy continuous), and choose accordingly a sequence $(x_n)_n \in (0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $0$. See what happens.